# C# - Code processing order - strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the follow button click event:

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;

        if (SelectDatabase())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFolderAddress.Text))
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a folder to begin the search.");
            else
            {

                if (cbRecurse.Checked == false || Directory.GetDirectories(initialDirectory).Length == 0)
                {
                    CheckSingleFolder();
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckSingleFolder();
                    directoryRecurse(initialDirectory);
                }

                                }
        }


    }
```

Effectively, it does a few checks and then starts some directory recursion looking for specific files.  However, the very first line of code to make the label visible does not occur until after the directories have been recursed?  Anybody know why this would be?

Thanks.

Comment: try refreshing your form if your function holds it, might help. `form1.refresh();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing everything within the UI thread, which is a really bad idea - the UI doesn't get to update, react to events etc until you've finished.

You should use a background thread and update the UI with progress etc using [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx), or perhaps use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Basically, there are two golden rules in WinForms (and similar with WPF/Silverlight):

- Don't do anything which can take a significant amount of time in the UI thread
- Don't touch any UI elements from any thread *other* than the UI thread

Comment: What would be the best way then to wait for the new thread to finish?  I have another method that has to wait until the recursion has finished.  If I use a seperate thread and then use something like while(thread.isalive){}, it obviously blocks the thread until the new thread is finished.    What would you recommend?  Thanks.

Comment: @Darren: Make the file-handling code marshal a call back to the UI thread, calling whatever method needs to continue afterwards (e.g. re-enabling the button etc).

Comment: Excellent thanks. So I simply, forexample, use something as such: btnRun.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { //Run Method });

Comment: @Darren: Yes, that sort of thing. Personally I prefer using `BeginInvoke` unless you *really* need the worker thread to block, but that's a minor point :)

Answer (score 1):

your whole method runs as a blocking unit currently - add an [`Application.DoEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) as a workaround, but really you should be doing this kind of processing in a background thread, i.e. using a background worker.

Comment: Blech. Application.DoEvents is a hack - this code should not be executing on the UI thread to start with.

Comment: And a very *dangerous* hack, at that. I'm glad you added that clarification; you narrowly escaped a downvote from me. ;-) There are just too many answers making ill-conceived recommendations to use `Application.DoEvents`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is executing on the same thread which is drawing your user-interface. Therefore, while the code is executing, your UI is not being re-drawn. Once the button-click code has finished, the UI is redrawn and `label1` gets drawn invisibly.

You can move your code into a separate thread using, for example, `Task` or `BackgroundWorker`. However, you cannot directly set UI properties from a different thread, so you will need to either be careful to set your UI properties from the UI thread or [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) about how to update the GUI from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

The view is not updated until the code block finished. So I would propose a [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) for the recursion part.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation: the label is set to visible and it it is Invalidated (needs repainting) but the Windows message pump doesn't start repainting until it is running idle. So your code blocks it.

A simple solution is to call `label1.Update()` right after setting it visible.

A better solution is to move the time-consuming code to a thread (Backgroundworker).